# Rails: Complicated query for nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to use eager loading to load a nested model's records, but only some of them.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :check_ins, -> { order(week: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :weigh_ins, :through => :check_ins, dependent: :destroy
end

class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    has_one :weigh_in, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If I start with a `CheckIn`, I can eager load the `check_in`'s `Client` as well as the `Client`'s `check_ins`.

```
CheckIn.includes(client: [:check_ins])
```

But if I only want the `client`'s `check_ins` with a certain field, I cannot seem to query that:

```
CheckIn.includes(client: [:check_ins]).where(clients: { check_ins: { foo: 'bar' }})
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not
`CheckIn.where(foo: 'bar')`
?

Comment: Can you paste your all models here to get clear idea and relations?

Comment: You got it! I've added them